# Bash pattern to match all files but directories

Tags: bash, directory, filenames, wildcards

In bash, how do I specify a pattern that matches everything but subdirectories in current directory. Given that the pattern `*/` matches all the subdirectories, I tried (with extglob turned on):

```
$ echo !(*/)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: A globbing pattern will match any name, it can not be made to distinguish between files and directories by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -type d
```

Details:

- `-maxdepth 1` restricts the search to the current directory
- `! -type d` eliminates directories

Comment: another variant that i use frequently is `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` this only matches regular files

Answer (score 6):

The reason `*/` matches directories is that the final `/` restricts matches to directories. This effect is only triggered when the `/` is after a pattern, you can't use `/` inside parentheses in `!(*/)`. There's no feature built into bash to do what you want.

You can make a loop over all files and build an array.

```
non_directories=()
for x in *; do
  [ -d "$x" ] || non_directories+=("$x")
done
somecommand "${non_directories[@]}"
```

You can also use `find`, if you want to execute a command over all files. If your find implementation supports it (GNU, BSD, BusyBox), use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` to list only entries in the current directories (with `./` prepended). Use `! -name '.*'` to omit dot files (if you indeed want to omit them).

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -exec somecommand {} +
```

If you can only assume a POSIX `find`, use `-prune` to avoid recursing.

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -exec somecommand {} +
```

If you want to stuff the output of `find` into an array variable, beware that parsing the output of `find` requires additional assumptions on the file name. You're better off with a loop.

In zsh, you can use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `*(^/)`, or `*(.)` to match only regular files.

Comment: What does the `-mindepth 1` do in your first example? You are already excluding directories with the `! -type d`, is there any point to using `-mindepth` as well? Also, your `-prune` example won't work, did you mean `-type f`?

Comment: @terdon I included `-mindepth 1` as a force of habit for a non-recursive use of `find`. I guess it doesn't hurt and if I left it out one could arguably wonder why. The second `find` command was a typo (braino?) of mine: `-name .` has to go first, otherwise `.` would end up pruned.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of long winded, but:

```
for f in *; do if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

`-d` is a [file test operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) to check if the argument is a directory.

The above could also be shortened to

```
for f in *; do [ ! -d "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: Correct answer and the link provided was really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which of the 2 options to you want to achieve - bash globing that excludes based on filesystem attributes, or a way to display only files in a directory?

If the first, I'm not sure that's possible. Globing just expands, and filenames are a base in any directory - bash doesn't distinguish between a file name or a dirname on it's own.

If the second - you already got 2 answers, another one using ls:

```
ls -dF * | grep -v "/$"
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
GLOBIGNORE=$(echo */)            # create list of directories with globbing
GLOBIGNORE=${GLOBIGNORE//:/\\:}  # escape possible ":" with "\" to allow
                                 # the separator ":" in directory names
GLOBIGNORE=${GLOBIGNORE//\/ /:}  # replace "/ " with separator ":" 
GLOBIGNORE=${GLOBIGNORE%/}       # remove trailing "/"
ls -ld *
```

Result: no directories

Back to default with `unset GLOBIGNORE`